# Filtering GeoJSON data using array of values to create Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, leaflet, geojson

I'm still new to coding so please forgive me if I'm not asking the right questions.

I have a JSON file with data from a number of countries and I want to use Leaflet to paint all the countries in that file on a map. To do so I'm using a GeoJSON file containing all the countries of the world, and I want to filter this GeoJSON file by "id" (which is a 3-letter country code) so that it only includes the countries in my array (also 3-letter country code).

I used D3.json to get an array of just the country codes from my JSON file, and then looped through that array to get each country in the list to filter my GeoJSON file:

```
  d3.json("countryList.json", function(data) {
    const countries = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.country))];
    console.log(countries);

    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
      var countryCode = countries[i];
      console.log(countryCode);
    };
```

I tried this with no luck:

```
L.geoJson(data, {
  filter: function(feature) }
    if (feature.id === countryCode) return True
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need d3 to filter your countries. Also, when you initialize a variable inside a for-loop, it's going to get overwritten unless you break from the loop. Anyways, take this example of filtering a single U.S. state out of 2 states and go from there:

```
var geojson_data = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"36","properties":{"name":"New York"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-73.343806,45.013027],[-73.332852,44.804903],[-73.387622,44.618687],[-73.294514,44.437948],[-73.321898,44.246255],[-73.436914,44.043608],[-73.349283,43.769761],[-73.404052,43.687607],[-73.245221,43.523299],[-73.278083,42.833204],[-73.267129,42.745573],[-73.508114,42.08834],[-73.486206,42.050002],[-73.55193,41.294184],[-73.48073,41.21203],[-73.727192,41.102491],[-73.655992,40.987475],[-73.22879,40.905321],[-73.141159,40.965568],[-72.774204,40.965568],[-72.587988,40.998429],[-72.28128,41.157261],[-72.259372,41.042245],[-72.100541,40.992952],[-72.467496,40.845075],[-73.239744,40.625997],[-73.562884,40.582182],[-73.776484,40.593136],[-73.935316,40.543843],[-74.022947,40.708151],[-73.902454,40.998429],[-74.236547,41.14083],[-74.69661,41.359907],[-74.740426,41.431108],[-74.89378,41.436584],[-75.074519,41.60637],[-75.052611,41.754247],[-75.173104,41.869263],[-75.249781,41.863786],[-75.35932,42.000709],[-79.76278,42.000709],[-79.76278,42.252649],[-79.76278,42.269079],[-79.149363,42.55388],[-79.050778,42.690804],[-78.853608,42.783912],[-78.930285,42.953697],[-79.012439,42.986559],[-79.072686,43.260406],[-78.486653,43.375421],[-77.966344,43.369944],[-77.75822,43.34256],[-77.533665,43.233021],[-77.391265,43.276836],[-76.958587,43.271359],[-76.695693,43.34256],[-76.41637,43.523299],[-76.235631,43.528776],[-76.230154,43.802623],[-76.137046,43.961454],[-76.3616,44.070993],[-76.312308,44.196962],[-75.912491,44.366748],[-75.764614,44.514625],[-75.282643,44.848718],[-74.828057,45.018503],[-74.148916,44.991119],[-73.343806,45.013027]]]}},{"type":"Feature","id":"48","properties":{"name":"Texas"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-101.812942,36.501861],[-100.000075,36.501861],[-100.000075,34.563024],[-99.923398,34.573978],[-99.698843,34.382285],[-99.57835,34.415147],[-99.260688,34.404193],[-99.189488,34.2125],[-98.986841,34.223454],[-98.767763,34.135823],[-98.570593,34.146777],[-98.488439,34.064623],[-98.36247,34.157731],[-98.170777,34.113915],[-98.088623,34.004376],[-97.946222,33.987946],[-97.869545,33.851022],[-97.694283,33.982469],[-97.458774,33.905791],[-97.371143,33.823637],[-97.256128,33.861976],[-97.173974,33.736006],[-96.922034,33.960561],[-96.850834,33.845545],[-96.631756,33.845545],[-96.423633,33.774345],[-96.346956,33.686714],[-96.149786,33.840068],[-95.936185,33.889361],[-95.8376,33.834591],[-95.602092,33.933176],[-95.547322,33.878407],[-95.289906,33.87293],[-95.224183,33.960561],[-94.966767,33.861976],[-94.868182,33.74696],[-94.484796,33.637421],[-94.380734,33.544313],[-94.183564,33.593606],[-94.041164,33.54979],[-94.041164,33.018527],[-94.041164,31.994339],[-93.822086,31.775262],[-93.816609,31.556184],[-93.542762,31.15089],[-93.526331,30.93729],[-93.630393,30.679874],[-93.728978,30.575812],[-93.696116,30.438888],[-93.767317,30.334826],[-93.690639,30.143133],[-93.926148,29.787132],[-93.838517,29.688547],[-94.002825,29.68307],[-94.523134,29.546147],[-94.70935,29.622824],[-94.742212,29.787132],[-94.873659,29.672117],[-94.966767,29.699501],[-95.016059,29.557101],[-94.911997,29.496854],[-94.895566,29.310638],[-95.081782,29.113469],[-95.383014,28.867006],[-95.985477,28.604113],[-96.045724,28.647929],[-96.226463,28.582205],[-96.23194,28.642452],[-96.478402,28.598636],[-96.593418,28.724606],[-96.664618,28.697221],[-96.401725,28.439805],[-96.593418,28.357651],[-96.774157,28.406943],[-96.801542,28.226204],[-97.026096,28.039988],[-97.256128,27.694941],[-97.404005,27.333463],[-97.513544,27.360848],[-97.540929,27.229401],[-97.425913,27.262263],[-97.480682,26.99937],[-97.557359,26.988416],[-97.562836,26.840538],[-97.469728,26.758384],[-97.442344,26.457153],[-97.332805,26.353091],[-97.30542,26.161398],[-97.217789,25.991613],[-97.524498,25.887551],[-97.650467,26.018997],[-97.885976,26.06829],[-98.198161,26.057336],[-98.466531,26.221644],[-98.669178,26.238075],[-98.822533,26.369522],[-99.030656,26.413337],[-99.173057,26.539307],[-99.266165,26.840538],[-99.446904,27.021277],[-99.424996,27.174632],[-99.50715,27.33894],[-99.479765,27.48134],[-99.605735,27.640172],[-99.709797,27.656603],[-99.879582,27.799003],[-99.934351,27.979742],[-100.082229,28.14405],[-100.29583,28.280974],[-100.399891,28.582205],[-100.498476,28.66436],[-100.629923,28.905345],[-100.673738,29.102515],[-100.799708,29.244915],[-101.013309,29.370885],[-101.062601,29.458516],[-101.259771,29.535193],[-101.413125,29.754271],[-101.851281,29.803563],[-102.114174,29.792609],[-102.338728,29.869286],[-102.388021,29.765225],[-102.629006,29.732363],[-102.809745,29.524239],[-102.919284,29.190146],[-102.97953,29.184669],[-103.116454,28.987499],[-103.280762,28.982022],[-103.527224,29.135376],[-104.146119,29.381839],[-104.266611,29.513285],[-104.507597,29.639255],[-104.677382,29.924056],[-104.688336,30.181472],[-104.858121,30.389596],[-104.896459,30.570335],[-105.005998,30.685351],[-105.394861,30.855136],[-105.602985,31.085167],[-105.77277,31.167321],[-105.953509,31.364491],[-106.205448,31.468553],[-106.38071,31.731446],[-106.528588,31.786216],[-106.643603,31.901231],[-106.616219,31.999816],[-103.067161,31.999816],[-103.067161,33.002096],[-103.045254,34.01533],[-103.039777,36.501861],[-103.001438,36.501861],[-101.812942,36.501861]]]}}]}
```

```
L.geoJSON(geojson_data, {
    filter: function(feature) {
        return feature.properties.name === "Texas";
    }
}).addTo(map);
```